# iOS - AWS developer authentication, User registration Process

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

In my application i am using AWS SDK for development. i am able to do all the operations except user registration(In Developer authentication). In AWS they mentioned that for user registration we have to write our own backend code. But i do not have any idea about backend. I am thinking that if amazon provides straight forward solution for user registration it would be helpful. And i gone through server side setup(amazon provided sample code), but there we can register the user through browser not through ios client.

In my application user registration contains emaild, username, password and photo selection options.

For user registartion (developer authentication), i have done more research, but i did not find any direct solution.

Can any one please provide direct solution or any good tutorial to implement our own backend for user registration.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I know why Down vote? This is not duplicate and direct answer is not available for this question. If you know please provide the answer in comments, it's helpful for me and someone also thanks .

Answer (score 5):

You have a couple options to use Amazon Cognito and providing a complete registration system for users without building a backend: OpenID Connect and Open Source.

**OpenID Connect**: Since Cognito Supports OpenID Connect-compliant identity providers, you can leverage products out there that federate/broker multiple social providers and expose the federated user via OpenID Connect which have special support for Cognito including [Ping Federate](https://www.pingidentity.com/en/blog/2014/10/31/using_pingfederate_as_an_openid_connect_provider_for_amazon_cognito.html), [Auth0](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/01/08/integrating-auth0-with-amazon-cognito-in-ios/), and [SecureAuth](https://www.secureauth.com/Resources/Blog/June-2015/Announcing-Full-Support-for-Integration-with-Amazo.aspx) to name a few. I also understood that [Okta](http://developer.okta.com/) provides an OpenID Connect identity provider so it might be worth looking into.

**Open Source**: [LambdaAuth](https://github.com/danilop/LambdAuth) is a bare bones project that leverages Lambda and Cognito to provide a registration and authentication backend. [Cognito Helper](https://github.com/olegabu/cognito-helper) is another one that appears to have more features and be more developed. If one of those have the features you need, they should be easy to deploy and run on server-less Lambda, so they're easy to maintain and you pay only for what you use.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will check into this.

Comment: Thanks Scott...This is very useful indeed. A lot of people would leverage such libraries now that one of the big players in BaaS is closed i.e. Parse.

Answer (score 1):

While the details of your registration process will depend on the needs of your application, you may want to consider using API Gateway to front the registration logic you write.

API Gateway will generate an SDK for you which you can use in your application to call your API.

You can have your application call your registration API which handles all of the logic for doing the backend portion of acquiring credentials: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/concepts/authentication-flow/#developer-authenticated-identities-authflow

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply, I already gone through this link theoretically understood the concept, but practically how to write backend registration code. I need basic registration example, through this we can register from App also, not from website. Please let me know if you have any basic examples, tutorials. It's very helpful for me. Thank you

Comment: And one more question, is it possible to do registration without using backend, by using Dynamo DB operations? Please let me know